# Facebook Dialog link description always includes site description as well as my custom description

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, caption

I am currently posting a message to the users stream using the iOS sdk. My post includes a link to a picture. When posting I provide a custom description which goes beneath the caption. This is done by setting the description property as detailed on the documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/. When I do this my description appears, but it is always followed by the site details. My post links to Imgur, so for example if my message was "This is my IMAGE", then the actual post will read:

"This is my IMAGE

Imgur is used to share photos with social networks and online communities, and has the funniest pictures from all over the Internet."

I want to post a description without the Imgur website information being included. Is this possible? How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm not sure how to fix that problem for iOS sdk as i'm not a iOS Developer, but still you may have some idea,

Did you try [Open Graph Tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) ?

Use URL Linter to Debug: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/ and

Here's a sample snippet:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="YOUR-POST-TITLE"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://YOUR-SITE-URL"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://YOUR-IMAGE-URL"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="YOUR-SITE-TITLE"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="YOUR-DESCRIPTION"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="YOUR-USER-ID"/>
</head>
.....
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think Graph Tags are quite what I want. They look to allow users to like a product, while I am trying to publish a message with a link onto their stream.

Comment: My problem is not how to post the message. My problem is why does the description I post include extra information that I did not add.

Answer (score 0):

I am also dealing with this...What I found was that what you are describing is the 'default' caption.  I'm not sure how you get rid of it, but if you set the caption argument to something reasonable it will replace the link information.

Comment: Finally got round to addressing this issue again today. This is the problem. I am setting the caption argument to "This is my IMAGE" and the caption is instead set to "This is my IMAGE   Imgur is used to share photos... over the internet". My caption is being appended to by the description of the site I am linking to.